# Nodejs illegal operation on a directory

Tags: node.js

Im trying to compile a folder of markdown files into a single PDF with `markdown-pdf` NPM package.

I have a simple script to do the job:

```
var mpdf = require('markdown-pdf');
var fs = require('fs');

var mDocs = fs.readdirSync('./understandinges6/manuscript/');
mDocs = mDocs.map(function(d) { return 'understandinges6/manuscript/' + d });

var Book = 'understandinges6.pdf';

mpdf().concat.from(mDocs).to(Book, function() {
    console.log("Created", Book);
});
```

But when i execute the script, this error appears:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
```

It's weird because i'm in my home folder with the respective permissions. I'm specifying the output folder/file in the script and just reading with `fs.readdirSync`.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Well isn't the error EISDIR obvious? I quess one or more files in mDocs IS DIR (is directory, not a file) try `console.log(mDocs);` to check it

Comment: mDocs is returning the correct array: [here is the snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/16400)

Comment: Seeing your answer means the array wasn't correct right? So there was a directory so i was right, wasn't i? And althought your docs.pop() works it's not reliable since if the folder wasn't the last in the array it wouldn't work. Better would be to use docs.filter to filter out everything without md extension

Comment: Yep, there are my solution... isn't the best, it just works for me. I'll update this soon.

Answer (score 0):

`mDocs = mDocs.map(function(d) { return 'understandinges6/manuscript/' + d });` you forgot to add "./". Rewrite to `mDocs = mDocs.map(function(d) { return './understandinges6/manuscript/' + d });`

Comment: Nope, there isn't the problem. Still trhowing me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, i get the problem here:

In the `manuscripts/` folder are a `images/` sub-folder with some png's. When the scripts tryed to read and transform `images/` from `.md` to `.pdf` the error was fired.

Here is the array with the images/ inside:

```
[ 'understandinges6/manuscript/00-Introduction.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/01-Block-Bindings.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/02-Strings-and-Regular-Expressions.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/03-Functions.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/04-Objects.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/05-Destructuring.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/06-Symbols.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/07-Sets-And-Maps.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/08-Iterators-And-Generators.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/09-Classes.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/10-Arrays.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/11-Promises.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/12-Proxies-and-Reflection.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/13-Modules.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/A-Other-Changes.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/B-ECMAScript-7.md',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/Book.txt',
  'understandinges6/manuscript/images' ]
```

Solution? Just `pop()` the `mDocs` array (now just `docs`):

```
var mpdf = require('markdown-pdf');
var fs = require('fs');

var mDocs = fs.readdirSync('understandinges6/manuscript/');
var docs = mDocs.map(function(d) { return 'understandinges6/manuscript/' + d });

docs.pop();

var Book = 'understandinges6.pdf';

mpdf().concat.from(docs).to(Book, function() {
    console.log("Created", Book);
});
```